# Нужна помощь по перемещению объектов с помощью триггера!

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Мне нужна помощь! Мне нужно чтобы платформа для раннера продолжалась, но чтобы не было никаких тотальных лагов, я решил прибегнуть к такому способу: использовать 4 платформы, которые двигаются влево, и если 1 платформа заденет триггер, то она переносится на координаты: x: 0, y: 0, z: 30, дело в том, что я не могу написать нормально скрипт... Сам скрин моей работы и скрипта я закреплю...[image: Unity]

```
`using UnityEngine;

public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject platform;
    public GameObject platform1;
    public GameObject platform2;
    public GameObject platform3;

    public float platformSpeed = 5f;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        platform.transform.position -= new Vector3(0, 0, platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        platform1.transform.position -= new Vector3(0, 0, platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        platform2.transform.position -= new Vector3(0, 0, platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        platform3.transform.position -= new Vector3(0, 0, platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Platform")
        {
            other.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 30);
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Я в юнити совсем не разбираюсь, но вы вроде платформу обновлять хотели, а тут обновляете коллайдер `other.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 30);`

Comment: Дело в том что программа не может предположить, что будет следующим если после того как обновиться 1 платформа

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы каждый объект под названием "Platform", если он дотрагивается до тригера, то он бы спавнился на координатах. Скорее всего я не понял ответ(я совсем недавно начал изучать unity, поэтому извиняюсь если туплю).

Comment: вот вам видоС вашей проблемой [vidos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xh1U0Bf6wKw)